# make file target $(%SYMBOLIC)

Tags: c++, c, makefile

Can anyone explain what $(%SYMBOLIC) means in the make file target below?

```
R_all:  $(%SYMBOLIC)
    $(CD_MAKE) $(BASE_ROOT)    R_all
```

Comment: Post the entire makefile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's just a variable called `%SYMBOLIC`.  Because of the `%` character, you can't set such a variable with a normal `=` or `:=` in the Makefile, but you can set it with `define` or in the environment if you run make directly with `execve`

Comment: You definitely can use either `=` or `:=` to assign a variable where the name contains a `%` character...?

Comment: I guess it may depend on the version of make as to whether it considers the `%` a special character that otherwise interferes with the assignment.

Comment: Possibly some make implementation will get it wrong, but no version of GNU make will make that mistake.  The GNU make parser first looks for a "separator" which is a colon or an equals sign etc. and once it finds that it interprets the rest of the line based on that.  So if the separator is an `=` or `:=`, then the first word will always be considered a variable name even if it contains a `%` character.